# R spatial: add new attribute to S4 class object?

Tags: r, spatial-analyst, rgeos

I am trying to check if my shapefile polygons have **open edge** or not. To have an open edge, the polygon either has no neighbors, or is >5 m taller than its neighbours. So, I want to add this new field `open_edge` TRUE or FALSE to my attribute table.

My idea was to loop through each polygon row by row (similar to arcpy.da.searchCursor in ArcGIS), and depending of the number of adjacent polygon fill in attribute value, or move to next row.

This is how I can fill in all values in a field:

```
polys@data$open_edge <- TRUE
```

**But within `for loop` i.e. subsetting by one row at time `polys[i, ]@data$open_edge <- TRUE` I got an error**:

```
Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

How can I insert new value to the attribute table row by row?

My code:

```
polys= readOGR(getwd(), 
                layer = "polys")

# Crete new vector to store open_edge value
polys@data$open_edge <- NA

for (i in seq_along(polys)) {
  one = polys[i, ]
  left = polys[-i,]

  # Identify the number of neighbors for each polygon
  nbrs <- left[which(gTouches(sp::geometry(one),
                              sp::geometry(left), 
                              byid = TRUE)),]

  if (nrow(nbrs) == 0) {
    polys[i, ]@data$open_edge <- TRUE  ## how to fill this???
    print("in if statement")
  } else {
    print ("something else")
    # compare here the tree heights of stands
    # ...
  }
}
```

I expect to get back filled attribute table in new filed:

```
polys@data$open_edge
TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer...

I had wrong position of the `[i,]` indexing. Instead of **indexing the shapefile** `polys[i,]@data$open_edge <- TRUE` the correct **indexing is in shapefile attribute table slot** `polys@data[i,]`:

```
`polys@data[i,]$open_edge <- TRUE`
```

The whole script:

```
# Crete new vector to store open_edge value
polys@data$open_edge <- NA

for (i in seq_along(polys)) {
  one = polys[i, ]
  left = polys[-i,]

  # Identify the number of neighbors for each polygon
  nbrs <- left[which(gTouches(sp::geometry(one),
                              sp::geometry(left), 
                              byid = TRUE)),]

  if (nrow(nbrs) == 0) {
    polys@data[i,]$open_edge <- TRUE  ## CORRECTED HERE !
    print("in if statement")
  } else {
    print ("something else")
    # compare here the tree heights of stands
    # ...
  }
}
```